# How to determine if a datetime has passed or not for Sydney Time

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I am trying to make a simple script. Essentially all it will do is tell me if the date I supply (`$dateToCheck`) has passed or is yet to coming up in the future. The program seems to work and everything but the issue is that the dates/time are not converting into Sydney time. I want all dates to be in Sydney time. So the script works if there is a huge time gap between the `$dateToCheck` and current time. However, if the current date and the `$dateToCheck` are only a few hours apart, it stops giving the correct answer. Hence, the problem is with timezones.

```
<?php
// All dates and time are in Sydney time
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$currTime = time();
$dateToCheck = "2019-06-08T18:00:00"; // 10th June 2018 at 7:00pm

$answer = has_date_past($currTime, $dateToCheck);
echo $answer;

// If the date has passed the current time, return true
function has_date_past($currTime, $date) {
    $checkDate = strtotime($date);
    echo $checkDate . "<br>";
    echo $currTime . "<br>";

    if ($currTime <= $checkDate) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects can be compared using standard comparison operators and have built-in timezone support.

Comment: @Sammitch What do you mean? Possible to show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
$oz = new DateTimezone('Australia/Sydney');
$now = new DateTime('now', $oz);
$dateToCheck = new DateTime("2019-06-08T18:00:00", $oz);

var_dump($now, $dateToCheck, $now <=> $dateToCheck);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-06-08 09:25:25.623080"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Australia/Sydney"
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-06-08 18:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Australia/Sydney"
}
int(-1)
```